# Copy TextBox to Cell Loop

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have 24 textboxes on a userform. I am looking for a loop to take textbox 1 and copy its value to "G7", then scroll down to the next cell in column G and copy Textbox 2 and so on

I am currently copying each text box on its own. I want to use scroll down as some of the cells are merged

```
Range("G7").Value = TextBox1.Value
Range("G8").Value = TextBox2.Value
Range("G13").Value = TextBox3.Value
Range("G19").Value = TextBox4.Value
```

I only want to stream line this as I have 3 different userforms to do this on

I have tried the following, but the code does not populate the cells:

```
Sheets("AssessCrit - PU").Select
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 24
With Me.Controls("TextBox" & i)
Range("G6").End(xlDown).Value = _
Array(TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, .Value)
End With
Next i
```

I have a working solution, Thank you everyone for their help:

```
Sub SelectNextVisibleCell(Rng As Range)
Dim Cel As Range
For Each Cel In Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(1000, 0))
If Cel.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
  Set Rng = Cel
  Exit Sub
End If
Next Cel
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("AssessCrit - PU").Range("G7").Select
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 24
Set Rng = ActiveCell
Call SelectNextVisibleCell(Rng)
Rng.Select
Rng.Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a moment to step through what your code is doing, line by line.  Currently, it is trying to overwrite the same cell 24 times, with an array instead of an actual value.

Comment: I have noticed that, but I am confusing myself on how to scroll through the TextBoxes then the Cells in the loop. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: As a rough, untested loop, you could try something like `For i = 1 to 24: Worksheets("AssessCrit - PU").Range("G5").Offset(0,i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text: Next i`

Answer (score 0):

Your issues at the moment seems to be the cells not getting properly cycled through which leaves one cell getting assigned an Array of text-boxes.

This here should solve your issues as it increments the cell used each loop as well as the TextBox:

```
Sheets("AssessCrit - PU").Select
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 24
    Range("G" & (6 + i)).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
Next i
Me.Controls = Nothing
```

(I use excel infrequently, focusing mainly on Access so if any of this code is wrong please let me know what to change.)

Comment: You missed an important bit of information that's not really clear in the question: *  I want to use scroll down as some of the cells are merged* The OP doesn't really mean "scroll down"... I think Down-Arrow is what is meant.

Comment: Hi Cindy, Thank you for that. Yes that is exactly what I mean. TextBox 1 goes to Cell G7 then down arrow and TextBox2 goes to the next Cell, then down arrow and so forth

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish. Starting at `G7` it tests each cell for a merged condition, if `True` then it will go to the next cell  `G8` to test it. If the cell is not merged, it will copy the textbox value, until it copies textbox 24.

```
Sub SkipMergedCells()
i = 7
    For x = 1 To 24
        If Range("G" & i).MergeCells = True Then
            i = i + 1
            x = x - 1

        ElseIf Range("G" & i).MergeCells = False Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value
            i = i + 1

        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Updated to reflect merged cells in ColG.

```
Sub SkipMergedCells()
i = 7
    For x = 1 To 24
        If Range("G" & i).MergeCells = True Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value

                            Dim mRowCnt As Long
            mRowCnt = Range("G" & i).MergeArea.Cells.Count

            i = i + mRowCnt
            x = x

        ElseIf Range("G" & i).MergeCells = False Then
            Range("G" & i).Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & x).Value
            i = i + 1

        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi All, Thank you for the help, I am playing with what you have given and yes I know using merged cells is a huge no no, but...... The cells in the column are a combination of merged and non merged and I want to be able to copy textbox 1 to cell G7 then the next cell is merged and textbox2 must be copied to that cell. Textbox 3 must then be copied to the next cell merged or not merged. I will appreciate some help, but will let you guys know if I get it to work the way it must.